# Dump database in MySQL Workbench 8.0.15 via url

Tags: mysql

My database url is like:
'http://website/name.sql'

I use MySQL Workbench 8.0.15 and think the workspace for data import changed. Also the commandlines:

```
curl 'http://website/name.sql' | mysql -u user dbname

curl 'http://website/name.sql’ | mysql -uuser -ppassword dbname

mysql -h user -u password -p db_name < http://website/name.sql
```

doesn't work.
So, I couldn't find how to import the database.

Any solutions?
Thnak you!

Comment: Why you does not try to path instant of url.

Comment: I only had an url from my partner